# can not hit breakpoint inside of .js file

Tags: javascript, debugging, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I upgraded to win 8. Now I run my VS 2012 under admin privileges and I'm creating a website in MVC 4. I checked different solutions online and none have worked. I have a javascript file in my solution but when I put a breakpoint in it, at runtime I see "no symbols have been loaded for this document". I had this issue couple years back with VS 2008 and somehow it resolved. I don't remember if I did change anything at all. Now it's back! except i'm not on win XP and VS 2008. the .pdb files are in place (bin\Debug), script debugging is enabled in internet options, and I can debug my c# code without any problem. totally the same situation I've been into back in 2008. whatever this is, is all about javascript since this happens for inline javascript too!

the strange part is that the js code is running but I just can't debug it in vs 2012.

I already know the workaround, which is using f12 tools or anything similar. That's not the case here, I had VS 2012 on win 7 two weeks ago and I was debugging my js in VS itself without any problems. this is the same installation, so it must be win 8 related.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: When do you add the breakpoints? While the app is running or before? What web development server are you using? is that IIS Express, IIS (full blown on the system) or cassini (Web development server)? If I read your explanation I think your problem is the fact you add the breakpoints to an other version of the file that the one that is running. That could explain why the js executes and you can't debug.

Comment: Already solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Turn your user account control settings off!**

If that doesn't work, create a new application (don't change anything!). Make sure JavaScript debugging is enabled in Internet Explorer.

If *that* doesn't work, then make sure JavaScript is enabled in the current Internet Security Zone (IE Options).

Answer (score 14):

You can use debugger for hitting your code. Just write

```
debugger;
```

before the line you want to debug and this will work.I think this will make your life easy.

Answer (score 3):

By using Visual Studio 2015, I found that breakpoints will only work when you run your project in internet explorer.

It will neither work for Firefox nor Chrome.

For Firefox you can use the Firebug (Firefox's plugin) to debug JavaScript as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check would be the property pages of your project to make sure your debugger type is **Script Only**. Just right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and check the **Debugging** page.

[image]

Comment: I found it, but there is only "Configuration" option, General and Debugging are not there.

Comment: +1 for the window direction. I found bunch of stuff OTHER THAN Debugging option, Fixed them, Still no luck!

Comment: Is this a Win8 metro (Windows App Store) project? Are there non-JS projects in your solution?

Comment: no, just a pure MVC 4 project. Nothing else. As I said, Experienced this before and it went away by itself!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I thought you were coding a Windows 8 Metro app using Javascript/HTML. I have no idea how to get this working in MVC.

Comment: this isn't about MVC or Metro. This is about an issue with VS IDE that doesn't load debug symbols for javascript.

Comment: I understand that. There are specific steps you can follow to get Javascript debugging working when developing a Metro app that I happen to know. It doesn't appear that the same sequence of steps can be followed to get this working in an MVC app.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your breakpoint in the very first instruction of your JavaScript file, your breakpoint is probably in a code which is not reached.